# How do I perform a comparison using a generator object ( pathlib.iterdir ) in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I have a ton of files in a directory named calls. All of these files contain **in their filenames** their creation date, ex: **20181022**_151012_kK029150d6.xml

I need to find all the files whose creation date is >= 180 days old.
I'm using pathlib to collect the file names and can print the file names.
I want to do something like this:

```
calls = Path('/Users/muh/Python/calls')
for fyle in calls.iterdir():
    datetime.strptime(fyle[:8], "%Y%m%d")
```

but I get *"PosixPath' object is not subscriptable"*

I need to compare the YYYYMMDD in each filename to the current YYYYMMDD, is all.

Comment: use `fyle.name[:8]`

Comment: @mr.zog, please check my answer if it works for you. I have updated my answer after looking into the comments & downvotes and now it is fine.

Comment: As an aside, please always use the generic [python] tag for any python questions

Comment: @mr.zog, again I have updated my answer with debug info, it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

As `@juanpa.arrivillaga` suggested to use `fyle.name[:8]`, that is nice.

> **Suggestion:** Whenever you are stuck in this kind of problem, just try to get the details of that object as follows (what are the defined attributes/methods for any object).

```
>>> contents = calls.iterdir()
>>> 
>>> content = contents.next()
>>> 
>>> content
PosixPath('/Users/hygull/Projects/django1.9.x-docs/Sfw/file_handling/calls/20181022_151012_kK029150d6.xml')
>>> 
>>> dir(content)
['__bytes__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__div__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__rdiv__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rtruediv__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '_accessor', '_cached_cparts', '_cparts', '_drv', '_flavour', '_format_parsed_parts', '_from_parsed_parts', '_from_parts', '_hash', '_init', '_make_child', '_make_child_relpath', '_opener', '_parse_args', '_parts', '_pparts', '_raw_open', '_root', '_str', 'absolute', 'anchor', 'as_posix', 'as_uri', 'chmod', 'cwd', 'drive', 'exists', 'glob', 'group', 'is_absolute', 'is_block_device', 'is_char_device', 'is_dir', 'is_fifo', 'is_file', 'is_reserved', 'is_socket', 'is_symlink', 'iterdir', 'joinpath', 'lchmod', 'lstat', 'match', 'mkdir', 'name', 'open', 'owner', 'parent', 'parents', 'parts', 'relative_to', 'rename', 'replace', 'resolve', 'rglob', 'rmdir', 'root', 'stat', 'stem', 'suffix', 'suffixes', 'symlink_to', 'touch', 'unlink', 'with_name', 'with_suffix']
>>>
```

In the above list, you will find the entry like `[..., 'mkdir', 'name', 'open', 'owner', 'parent', ...]` where you can see `'name'` is the part of it. So finally, you can try to access like `fyle.name` | `type(fyle.name)` etc. to check if it is a string or anything else.

### Solution:

So, you can do like this.

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime

calls = Path("/Users/muh/Python/calls")
details = {}

i = 1
for fyle in calls.iterdir():
    date = datetime.strptime(fyle.name[:8], "%Y%m%d")

    # Write logic here
```

### Detailed:

In the below code, I've stored details into a dictionary so that you could have a look into the different states of object that changed in the code.

> In my case, the path to `calls` directory is `/Users/hygull/Projects/django1.9.x-docs/Sfw/file_handling/calls`.

I have stored each bit & pieces to help you figuring out the problem. I did not try to introduce new variables except **d** & **details** & also reused your variable named **fyle** multiple times for different purpose (It is good if don't have any further use of that variable in simple programs & it is also good to introduce meaningful variable names for big applications).

> **date** is the actual datetime object that you can use for manipulation to achieve your final goal.

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime

calls = Path("/Users/hygull/Projects/django1.9.x-docs/Sfw/file_handling/calls")
details = {}

i = 1
for fyle in calls.iterdir():
    d = {}
    d["pathlib"] = fyle

    fyle = str(fyle)
    d["fullpath"] = fyle

    # fyle = fyle.split("/")[-1]
    fyle = fyle.name[:8]
    d["file_name"] = fyle

    date = datetime.strptime(fyle[:8], "%Y%m%d")
    d["date"] = date

    # Write your business logic here

    details["file" + str(i)] = d
    i += 1

print(details)
```

> Output

```
{'file2': {'date': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 25, 0, 0), 'file_name': '20181025_151013_kK029150d7.xml', 'fullpath': '/Users/hygull/Projects/django1.9.x-docs/Sfw/file_handling/calls/20181025_151013_kK029150d7.xml', 'pathlib': PosixPath('/Users/hygull/Projects/django1.9.x-docs/Sfw/file_handling/calls/20181025_151013_kK029150d7.xml')}, 'file1': {'date': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 22, 0, 0), 'file_name': '20181022_151012_kK029150d6.xml', 'fullpath': '/Users/hygull/Projects/django1.9.x-docs/Sfw/file_handling/calls/20181022_151012_kK029150d6.xml', 'pathlib': PosixPath('/Users/hygull/Projects/django1.9.x-docs/Sfw/file_handling/calls/20181022_151012_kK029150d6.xml')}}
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thank you very much for your great suggestion. I was blind, could not see if the question is related to using `pathlib` then why I suggested to use `os` here. I have commented that line and used the alternative to get base name from file path. Thank you again for pointing my mistake.

Comment: No @juanpa.arrivillaga, there is not an actual use of that here. May be, it is little awkward as it is not the part of your problem. First time, when I was not aware of using `.name`, I presented to solve the problem in different way. At that time I thought to note & store each details of transformation.

Comment: Now, I updated my answer. I know you have already solved it. Just to clear the doubts I separated my answer in 2 parts. Consider 1st one as working. 2nd one is detailed (Useful for debugging this kind of problem). Thank you for writing back.